# What are the guidelines for editing FAQ's?

Tags: discussion, edits, meta

[There are plenty of FAQ's on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq).

But I'm curious - what exactly are the guidelines for editing them?

Can anyone just edit them at any time (subject to reputation restrictions, of course, which are fairly low)?

When should I edit it?

Should I get approval to make sure that what I believe to be true is true before editing it?

Shouldn't someone make sure they're still right after they've been edited?

I would assume that having them be correct most, if not all, of the time should be pretty important, as they're either guidelines for how to use the site, or explanations for how the site works.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone just edit them at any time (subject to reputation restrictions, of course, which are fairly low)?

Yes.

> When should I edit it?

Whenever you see something wrong, broken, missing or out of date; update and improve the FAQ, similar to any other *community* wiki resource.

> Should I get approval to make sure that what I believe to be true is true before editing it?

Approval? Not necessarily. A reference, screenshot, or something to back up your edit would certainly help and provide validity.

> Shouldn't someone make sure they're still right after they've been edited?

Yes. That's all of **us**. Obviously, it is the primary responsibility of the editor to avoid any errors. We should also ensure that if any such edits happen while we happen to be online, or if we come across them, then we should take a look to make sure that the edit is fine.